# How much information does a geotagged picture contain ? or specifically can contain?

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, metadata, geotagging

This is an open ended question. With the capabilities of current geo-enabled phones and cameras (based on gps) when a geo-enabled picture is taken at a certain location

What all metadata is added to the picture ? Or rather based on other information within the phone (its location, time, surroundings (nearest city ?)) what more information can be added ?

Comment: "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: These data are stored in [EXIF tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format). It really can potentially include *anything*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These data usually consist of latitude and longitude coordinates, though they can also include altitude, bearing, distance, accuracy data, and place names.

[Geotagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging)